# Cantor–Bendixson Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Prove that every uncountable closed set $F$ in $R^n$ can be written as $$F=A \cup B$$ where $A$ is a perfect set and set $B$ is a countable set.
$$$$Perfect Set: A set in which all points are accumulation points.
Condensation Point: A point $x$ in $R^n$ is set to be a condensation Point of a set $S$ in $R^n$ if every open n-ball $B(x)$ of $x$ is such that $$B(x) \cap S$$ is uncountable.
$$$$Let $A$ be the set of all condensation points of $F$ lying in $F$ then consider the set $F-A$. If $x$ lies in the set $F-A$ then there exists a open n-ball $B(x)$ of $x$ such that $$B(x) \cap F$$ is countable and hence $$B(x) \cap F-A$$ is countanle. Now for every $x$ in $F-A$ if we chose an open n-ball with the above stated property then this collection of open n-balls is an open covering of $F-A$ and hence by Lindelof's Covering Theorem there exists a countable number of such open n-ball that cover $F-A$ and as each of these open balls contain only a countable number of elements of $F-A$ as stated above we get that the set $F-A$ is countable. So let us chose $$B=F-A$$. Now chose any $x$ in $A$ then for every open n-ball we have $$B(x) \cap F$$ is uncountable. Now suppose there exists a open n-ball $C(x)$ such that $$C(x) \cap A= \phi$$ but as $$C(x) \cap F$$ is uncountable and the set $B=F-A$ is countable so $$C(x) \cap F$$ cannot be uncountable, a contradiction. So every point $x$ in the set $A$ is an accumulation point and the set $A$ is a perfect set.
$$$$Is My Proof Correct??

Comment: I observe: (1) You use the two terms "accumulation point" and "condensation point" and I do not know if you mean these to be the same, or different; (2) By Googling "perfect set" I find a wikipedia link that defines a perfect set as a set that is closed and that has no isolated points (so at least the "closed" property seems missing from the definition you give).

Comment: By accumulation point I mean that a point of a set  whose every open n-ball contains atleast one point of that set except this point.

Comment: Also it can be proved that set $A$ is closed. So now is my proof Correct??

Comment: Your proof starts: "Perfect Set: A set in which all points are accumulation points." If this first line is incorrect, then your proof is incorrect.  If this first line is correct, you may want to emphasize that your working-definition of "perfect set" differs from the wikipedia definition I found (and you may want to clarify the role of your previous comment "Also it can be proved that set A is closed").  If this first line is intended to be ignored, and the wikipedia definition used, your proof is incorrect since saying "it can be proved A is closed" is not a correct proof.

Comment: If we chose any $x$ in the complement of the set $A$ then there exists an open n-ball $B(x)$ such that $B(x) \cap F$ is countable. Now in that open ball if we chose any point $c$ then there exists an open ball $B(c)$ such that $B(c)$ lies in $B(x)$ and hence $B(c) \cap F$ is also countable, so for every $x$ in the complement of the set $A$ there exists an open n-ball such that all the points in this open n-ball also lie in the complement of the set $A$ and hence the complement is the set $A$ is an open set and hence set $A$ is a closed set.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, your proof is at best incomplete: a perfect set is a **closed** with no isolated points (or, if you prefer, a **closed** set whose every point is an accumulation point of the set). Your proof that $F\setminus A$ is countable is correct but more complicated than necessary. Your proof that every point of $A$ is an accumulation point of $A$ contains a technical error, and you still have to prove that $A$ is closed.

In proving that $F\setminus A$ is countable there is no need to appeal to the Lindelöf property. $\Bbb R^n$ has a countable base $\mathscr{B}$, so for each $x\in F\setminus A$ we can simply choose a $B_x\in\mathscr{B}$ such that $x\in B_x$ and $B_x\cap F$ is countable. Let $\mathscr{B}_0=\{B_x:x\in F\setminus A\}$; $\mathscr{B}_0\subseteq\mathscr{B}$, so $\mathscr{B}_0$ is countable, and

$$F\setminus A\subseteq F\cap\bigcup\mathscr{B}_0=\bigcup_{B\in\mathscr{B}_0}(F\cap B)\;.$$

That last union is a countable union of countable sets, so it’s countable and therefore so is $F\setminus A$.

To prove that $A$ has no isolated points, you want to show that if $x\in A$, then each open ball centred at $x$ contains a point of $A\setminus\{x\}$, so you let $C(x)$ be an open ball centred at $x$; so far, so good. But then you suppose that $C(x)\cap A=\varnothing$, and this is clearly impossible, since $x\in C(x)\cap A$. If you’re going to argue by contradiction, you should instead assume that $C(x)\cap A=\{x\}$. However, there’s reason to use proof by contradiction here: just observe that if $C(x)$ is an open ball centred at $x\in A$, then $C(x)\cap A=\big(C(x)\cap F\big)\setminus B$, where $C(x)\cap F$ is uncountable and $B$ is countable, so $C(x)\cap A$ is uncountable and therefore certainly contains points of $A$ different from $x$.

To show that $A$ is closed, let $x\in X\setminus A$. $F$ is closed, so if $x\notin F$, then $X\setminus F$ is an open nbhd of $x$ disjoint from $A$. The only other possibility is that $x\in B$, in which case $B_x$ (see above) is an open nbhd of $x$ disjoint from $A$. It follows that $X\setminus A$ is open and hence that $A$ is closed.

---

It’s possible to modify the proof slightly so that the fact that $A$ is closed comes for free. Simply let $\mathscr{B}$ be a countable base for $\Bbb R^n$, and let $\mathscr{B}_0=\{B\in\mathscr{B}:B\cap F\text{ is countable}\}$. Let $A=F\setminus\bigcup\mathscr{B}_0$; clearly $A$ is a closed set of condensation points of $F$. Moreover, $\mathscr{B}_0$ is countable, so

$$F\setminus A=F\cap\bigcup\mathscr{B}_0=\bigcup_{B\in\mathscr{B}_0}(F\cap B)$$

is countable. The proof that $A$ has no isolated points is the same as before.